Intersection of commutator subgroup and normalizer of a $p$-Sylow subgroup is normal in $G$
I've been trying to solve the following question without much success and I'm kind of lost on what else I could try to do:
Assume that the commutator subgroup $G^{'} = [G,G]$ of a finite group $G$ is abelian. Let $p$ be a prime divisor of $|G|$, $P$ be a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $G$ and $N_{G}(P) = \left\{ g \in G : gPg^{-1} = P \right\}$ be the normalizer of $P$ in $G$. Show that $G^{'} \cap N_{G}(P)$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.
I've tried some things, but none of them seem to be leading me anywhere and here are my ideas so far:
Let $[h,k] = hkh^{-1}k^{-1} \in G^{'} \cap N_{G}(P)$ and $g \in G$. Since $G^{'}$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, we already know that $g[h,k]g^{-1} \in G^{'}$, so the only thing that's left to prove is that $g[h,k]g^{-1} \in N_{G}(P)$, that is, we need to show that $(g[h,k]g^{-1}) P (g[h,k]^{-1}g^{-1}) = P$. Since $[h,k] \in N_{G}(P)$, we have that $[h,k]^{-1}P[h,k] = P$ and, hence, $(g[h,k]g^{-1}) P (g[h,k]^{-1}g^{-1}) = (g[h,k]g^{-1}[h,k]^{-1}) P ([h,k]g[h,k]^{-1}g^{-1})$ (note that $g[h,k]g^{-1}[h,k]^{-1} \in G^{'}$, which is why I think this could be useful, but I'm not sure about that and I haven't been able to make much progress from here).
Another line of thought that I was trying to follow is that because $G^{'}$ is abelian, we know that every subgroup of $G^{'}$ is normal in $G^{'}$. In particular, $G^{'} \cap P$ and $G^{'} \cap N_{G}(P)$ are normal in $G^{'}$, but, even though $G^{'}$ is normal in $G$, we're still not able to conclude that $G^{'} \cap N_{G}(P)$ is normal in $G$ because, in general, being a normal subgroup is not a transitive relation. Also, since $G^{'} \cap P$ is normal in $G^{'}$, we have that whenever we conjugate $G^{'} \cap P$ by an element of $G^{'}$, we get $G^{'} \cap P$ and, thus, $(g[h,k]g^{-1}[h,k]^{-1}) (G^{'} \cap P) ([h,k]g[h,k]^{-1}g^{-1}) = G^{'} \cap P$ (again, I'm not sure whether this equality or the fact that $G^{'} \cap P$ is the unique $p$-Sylow subgroup of $G^{'}$ could actually be useful or not and I haven't made much progress from here).
A third thought that I had is that $(g[h,k]g^{-1}) P (g[h,k]^{-1}g^{-1})$ is also a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $G$, so we know that it's conjugate to $P$ and at least we have that there exists $a \in G$ such that $(g[h,k]g^{-1}) P (g[h,k]^{-1}g^{-1}) = aPa^{-1}$ but again, I haven't made much progress from here.
Maybe I could also try showing that the normalizer of $G^{'} \cap N_{G}(P)$ in $G$ is equal to $G$, but I'm not sure on how one could approach that?
Sorry for the long post and any hints or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

To the very least I need more coffee to solve this. But, the question would be trivial, if $G$ were nilpotent, right? Given what you know about $G$, it's "not very far from being nilpotent" (my ignorance shows right here!). I suggest you dig into your supply of examples of non-nilpotent groups $G$ such that  $[G,G]$ is abelian, and see how the land lies. Just to get ideas!

I don't have the full answer, but you cannot assume that an element of $G'\cap N_G(P)$ is of the form $[h,k]$. The commutator subgroup is generated by the commutators, but not every element needs to be a commutator.

@JyrkiLahtonen Metabelian groups (commutator is abelian) can be "very far from nilpotent". $S_3$ is metabelian. But the center is trivial and the lower central series stabilizes after a single step.

Thanks @ArturoMagidin.  Rummaging my supply of example of metabelian non- nilpotent groups... :-)

Anyway, more context could help. Where did you run into this question? What material preceded it?

Can't spend more time on this, but the exercise I give to myself is to figure out what's going on with the group $G$ of upper triangular invertible $2\times2$ matrices with entries from $\Bbb{Z}_{21}$. Unless I fumbled it, then you have primes  $p$ such that A) $p$ is a factor of $|G'|$ but not a factor of $|G/G'|$, B) $p$ is a factor of $|G/G'|$ but not a factor of $|G'|$, C) $p$ is a factor of both.

Try the Frattini argument using the normal subgroup $N=P[G,G]$.

Let $N = P[G,G]$.
Then, since $N$ contains $[G,G]$ it is normal in $G$, and by the Frattini Argument we have $G = N_G(P)N = N_G(P)[G,G]$.
Now $N_G(P) \cap [G,G]$ is normal in both $N_G(P)$ and in $[G,G]$ (because $[G,G]$ is abelian), so it is normal in $G$.

Right, thank you. I was also considering to somehow use the Frattini argument and pretty much what I was missing was the easy statement that $N_{G}(P) \cap [G,G]$ is normal in $N_{G}(P)$. Just a quick question. Doesn't the Frattini argument give us the equality $G = [G,G]N_{G}(P)$ directly from the property that $[G,G]$ is normal in $G$? Not that your answer is incorrect, but just curious about it.

I don't see how that would work, because $P$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$, not of $[G,G]$.
